# Enum inside an enum

Tags: c#, methods, enums

I wrote this code in Java. I have these two Enums and I wanted to know if it was possible to write an enum equivalent to UnitType in C #, as it continues to give me errors.

```
public enum GenericUnitType {
    BASIC, 
    NORMAL,
    HERO;
}
```

```
public enum UnitType {

    CLOSE_BASIC(GenericUnitType.BASIC),
    DISTANCE_BASIC(GenericUnitType.BASIC),
    CLOSE_NORMAL(GenericUnitType.NORMAL),
    DISTANCE_NORMAL(GenericUnitType.NORMAL),
    HERO_CLOSE_FIGHTER(GenericUnitType.HERO),
    HERO_DISTANCE_FIGHTER(GenericUnitType.HERO);


    private GenericUnitType genericType;

    UnitType(final GenericUnitType genericType) {
        this.genericType = genericType;
    }

    public GenericUnitType getGenericUnitType() {
        return this.genericType;
    }
}
```

Comment: c# doesn't have that. you'll have to map it someother way

Comment: No, Enums only contain named constants, no methods or constructors. You can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: `enums` in C# aren't classes. You can't define methods on them. Essentially, they are aliases for specific values

Comment: While you cannot put methods or variables in enums in C# you can write extension methods for enums in other classes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you can get is a `class`...

```
public enum GenericUnitType {
    BASIC, 
    NORMAL,
    HERO;
}

public class UnitType
{
    public static GenericUnitType CLOSE_BASIC = new UnitType(GenericUnitType.BASIC);
    public static GenericUnitType DISTANCE_BASIC = new UnitType(GenericUnitType.BASIC),
    public static GenericUnitType CLOSE_NORMAL = new UnitType(GenericUnitType.NORMAL),
    public static GenericUnitType DISTANCE_NORMAL = new UnitType(GenericUnitType.NORMAL),
    public static GenericUnitType HERO_CLOSE_FIGHTER = new UnitType(GenericUnitType.HERO),
    public static GenericUnitType HERO_DISTANCE_FIGHTER = new UnitType(GenericUnitType.HERO);

    private GenericUnitType _unitType;

    public UnitType(GenericUnitType unitType)
    {
        _unitType = unitType;
    }

    public GenericUnitType UnitType => _unitType;
}
```

Which should give you the same effect. C# does not have the feature of treating `enum`'s like classes that you can in Java.